# How do I have a rotation that follow with your mouse correctly - Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

http://jsfiddle.net/avPf6/1056/

The code is working, but the rotation is confused and no follow the mouse correctly:

```
ele.css('position', 'relative');
$('#handle').draggable({
  opacity: 0.01,
  helper: 'clone',
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui);
    var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + ui.position.left + 'deg)';

    $(this).parent().css({
      '-moz-transform': rotateCSS,
      '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS
    });
  }
});
```

How do I rotate correct?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the [rotatable.js script](https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable/blob/master/jquery.ui.rotatable.js) to achieve this. It will preform all the calculations necessary to rotate the element properly.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/oeddvaod/)

In doing so, you can actually simplify your jQuery down to the following. Here is a basic example using the HTML/CSS you provided:

```js
$('.draggable').draggable().rotatable({
  handle: $('.draggable .handle')
});
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.draggable .handle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ui.rotatable/1.0.1/jquery.ui.rotatable.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="draggable">
    <div class="handle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Josh Crozier, I'm trying to keep the organization of the z-index, where it is possible to choose which image is below or above, I updated the JSFlidde: http://jsfiddle.net/wJUHF/260/

Comment: @Zeli I don't quite understand what you're asking. Did my answer not address your initial question?

Comment: I've tried using the plugin Earlier, the plugin but can not apply the z-index property so plugin que Each Time you select or drag the image the z-index stay the other top. As in the example I sent you. So I wanted a solution without the plugin. In the example, the same image can be cloned several times to be dragged